# Dask - how to assign task to the specific CPU

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I'm using Dask to process research batches, which are quite heavy (from few minutes to few hours). There's no communication between the tasks and they produce only side results. I'm using a machine which already virtualizes resources beneath it (~ 30 CPUs), so I'm just running `LocalCluster`. Is there any way to assign a specific CPU to a task? In [docs](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/resources.html) there're only examples with gpu and memory.

I've tried to assign CPU in a similar way, but the tasks won't even start to process.

```py
client.submit(process, d, resources={'CPU': 1}) for d in data]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely reason that the tasks didn't start when you specified

```py
client.submit(process, d, resources={'CPU': 1}) for d in data]
```

is that the cluster was initiated without specifying that each worker had that resource (this has to be done at the time workers are started). Here's how to make sure that workers have that resource:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
cluster = LocalCluster(resources={'CPU': 1})
client = Client(cluster)
```

For finer-grained control, it is possible to assign tasks to specific workers. First, get the addresses of each worker with

```py
list_workers = list(client.scheduler_info()['workers'])
```

Then specify which worker(s) can complete the task:

```py
# submit for completion only by the first worker in the list
results_specific_worker = [client.submit(process, d, workers=list_workers[0]) for d in data]

# submit for completion by the first two workers
results_specific_workers = [client.submit(process, d, workers=list_workers[0:2]) for d in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is best achieved by limiting the number of *workers* ([`cluster.scale(3)`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/single-distributed.html)) and setting their [process niceness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix))

CPU time-sharing is really managed by the operating system

Comment: The problem is I'm doing some TensorFlow underneath and I don't have GPU's, so I'm already assigning NN training to specific CPU.