# Multiprocessing and Dask

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

**Scenario:** I want to perform simple computation on a file (~100 MB). I have thousands of such files. For this example, consider the computation to be "count the number of lines".

**Dask:** I am using Dask to parallelize read and computation.

**What works:** If each file is very large (45 GB), it makes sense to dedicate 1 computer (70GB memory) in my cluster (12 computers using PBS) to read and compute.

```
from dask_jobqueue import PBSCluster
cluster = PBSCluster(cores=1,processes=1,memory='70GB',queue='extra',project='abcd',walltime='12:00:00',interface='ib0',local_directory='/home/abcd/dask_workers/')
cluster.scale(jobs=12)
print(cluster.job_script())
from dask.distributed import Client, progress
client = Client(cluster)
```

**Problem:** When the file is small (~100 MB), I want 1 computer in the cluster to read and do the computation for multiple files in parallel.

**Question:** Which parameter will allow 1 computer in the cluster to undertake multiple read and computes, in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

How about specifying some arbitrary resource? E.g. specify `resources={'compute_load': 12}` when the cluster is created, to give each worker 12 units of resource `compute_load`.

When processing heavy load, assign `.compute(resources={'compute_load': 12})`, so each worker taken on only one task at a time. When the load is light, use `.compute(resources={'compute_load': 1})`, and each worker will take up 12 tasks at a time. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66166430/10693596).

Comment: I do not think this worked. Here is how I set it up:
`cluster = PBSCluster(resources={'compute_load':12},cores=1,memory='10 GB',queue='extra',project='abcd',walltime='10:00:00',interface='ib0',local_directory='/home/abcd/dask_workers/')`
`cluster.scale(12)`
`client = Client(cluster)`
`futures = [client.submit(functionToProcess,inputFile,resources={'compute_load':1}) for eachFile in intake]`

Comment: THat looks good except I think you want to use `futures = [client.submit(functionToProcess,inputFile,resources={'compute_load':12}) for eachFile in intake]` with the heavy files.

Comment: also note that with a single core per worker, they won't be able to do anything in parallel...

Comment: This setup is for light load. Each worker has two processors with 6 cores each.

Comment: hmm, `cores=1` means that a single core should be assigned per worker...