# Prevent dask from spreading tasks on multiple threads per each worker

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, joblib

I am using dask on LSF cluster to process some images in parallel. The processing function itself uses joblib to perform multiple computations on the image in parallel.

It seems that setting `n_workers` and `cores` parameters to some numbers will generally produce `n_workers * cores` futures running at the same time. I would like to have `n_workers` futures being processesed at a time, each of them having `cores` cores at disposal for the purpose of using them with joblib.

How do I achieve such result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dask - how to assign task to the specific CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162626/dask-how-to-assign-task-to-the-specific-cpu)

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev I am not sure, maybe? Do you suggest that I could solve the problem by setting each Worker to have available resource of 1 CPU and then each task to also require 1 CPU? I can only test it tommorow. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes, if I understand the situation correctly, that should resolve it.